# SQL Server, get Date of a week number

Tags: sql-server, date, week-number

I have a query to show the Number of payments, grouped by the week number in SQL Server 2012.

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(wk, FPP.UPLOAD_DATE) AS "Date by week", 
    COUNT(DISTINCT FPP.ID) AS "Number of Bills")
FROM 
    FACT_PAY_PAYMENT FPP 
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(wk, FPP.UPLOAD_DATE);
```

Small problem, when I do this code, I receive the week number, but I want the starting date of the week.

For example, now I receive following output:

```
 Date by week     Number of Bills 
 ---------------------------------
      40                 7
```

What I want to receive is:

```
 Date by week     Number of Bills 
 ---------------------------------
 2015-09-28            7
```

Comment: I do not understand... The 8th of September in 2015 is a Tuesday. Is there a reason for this date?

Comment: Had to be the 28th, thx

Comment: OK, so my answer should be correct...

Comment: how do you define the starting date of the week ? Is it the first day of the week(this could be an issue the first week of the year) or the monday or the sunday of the week ? Is this a US week or an ISO week, or some strange combination ?

Answer (score 5):

First you have to make sure what is the Datefirst of week `SELECT @@DATEFIRST;`,
In my machine `Sunday` is a `First day of week`

```
DECLARE @dt DATE = '2015-09-08';
SELECT DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,@dt),6) AS Datebyweek
```

Result

```
Datebyweek
2015-09-06 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DATEDIFF()` to get the number of weeks from the beginning and then `DATEADD()` to get the first date . For example;

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = GETDATE()

SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @date) , 0) FirstDayOfWeek
```

You can apply it to your query replacing @date with your column name. It would be like;

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, FPP.UPLOAD_DATE) , 0) AS "Date by week", 
    COUNT(DISTINCT FPP.ID) AS "Number of Bills"
FROM 
    FACT_PAY_PAYMENT FPP 
GROUP BY 
    DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, FPP.UPLOAD_DATE) , 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
DECLARE @d AS DATETIME =GETDATE();

SELECT DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,@d) AS WeekIndex
      ,DATEADD(DAY,DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@d) * (-1) /* The following "+1" is depending on system's culture, look at DATEFIRST !!! */ + 1 ,@d) AS MondayForThisWeek
```

This will come back with the week's index for a given date and the Monday in this week.

Be aware of some issues with system's culture (especially DATEFIRST !!!), week index on the year's ending and dates in general (included time component).

Answer (score 0):

The following function has helped me:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetFirstDateOfWeek] (@YearNum int, @WeekNum int)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN 

DECLARE @FirstWeekDay As Date;

SET @FirstWeekDay = dateadd (week, @WeekNum, dateadd(year, @YearNum-1900, 0)) - 4 - datepart(dw, dateadd(week, @WeekNum, dateadd (year, @YearNum-1900, 0)) - 4) + 1

RETURN @FirstWeekDay
END
```